# Do i need to install some packages to run javascript on debian

Tags: javascript, webserver

I have to set up a web server using a existing code done by an other intern.
I have a web server on debian, I've already set up the web server and it works.
When I copied his code on the server, I noticed that it doesn't work perfectly. 
His code contains some javascript and I want to know if I have to download some further packages on my debian server to let it run properly.

I have tried his code before on a WAMP server and I didn't got a problem when runnig his code, that's why I thought that maybe the reason was the javascript present on his code.

I've done some research on google and I have many links on Node.js but I can't really understand how It will solve my problem.

Thank you for reading my post and also for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/javascript-common

I am interested about debian too, but still a newbie here...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didn't need to install any packages, it was due to a problem with my database